# Change Tint of Navigation Controller's Toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I'm trying to design my app's interface in IB using a storyboard and have a UINavigationController connected to a UITableViewController. In the attributes inspector, I set the navigation controller's "Bottom Bar" property to "Toolbar". However, when I select the  Toolbar and try to change its tint, I am unable to - no matter what color I select, the tint remains at Default. What's weird is, I have the navigation controller's "Top Bar" property set to "Navigation Bar", and I'm able to change it's tint just fine. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere that the storyboard is only to help you visualize the layout of the toolbar.

You can change the color of the toolbar in your root view controller's view did load method using:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I just decided to scrap the toolbar and use the nav bar instead, but if I get a chance, I'll test your answer.